# SwiftUI array does not update parent view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am facing the issue that changes to the array items are not propagated to the parent view. The text in the inner view does get updated. However, changes to the same item are not displayed in the parent.

This is an extremely reduced version of my issue. Removing the array or manually sending objectWillChange is, in my opinion, not a good solution as It is quite likely to forget it. Changing the ViewModel to a struct does not work for me as I am updating the ViewModel from multiple places.

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var label: String = ""
    @Published var big: Bool

    init(label: String, big: Bool) {
        self.big = big
        self.label = label
    }
}

class ArrayViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [ViewModel]

    init(items: [ViewModel] = [ViewModel]()) {
        self.items = items
    }

    init() {
        self.items = [ViewModel]()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var items = ArrayViewModel(items: [ViewModel(label: "view ex", big: true)])
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< items.items.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(items.items[index].big ? "big" : "small")
                Button("outer toggle") {
                    items.items[index].big.toggle()
                }
                InnerCard()
                    .environmentObject(items.items[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InnerCard: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var currentItem: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text(currentItem.big ? "big" : "small")
        Button("inner toggle") {
            currentItem.big.toggle()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think `objectWillChange` is not a good solution? An alternative would be to use `@Observable`, but it’d be even better to just not use classes. Use structs instead.

Comment: Indices are not safe to use with `ForEach`

Comment: @Sweeper Because there are many different places from which I want to update the ViewModel, the probability is quite high that I will forget it somewhere. Structs can't be updated.

Comment: Structs can definitely be updated. In fact, SwiftUI is arguably much better at detecting changes in structs, since you don’t even need a property wrapper like `@Published`.

Comment: Please show an example of how you are updating the view model “from multiple places”. It is likely that you can refactor this to a single observable object, or no classes at all, with the different struct values connected with `@Binding`.

Comment: Also, having a “view model” at all, is overcomplicating things. SwiftUI doesn’t need an extra view model. The `View` struct that you write ***is*** literally the view model. SwiftUI creates the actual views for you, based on your `View` structs.

Comment: Your question title says "...array does update parent view." The body of your question says "...array items are not propagated to the parent view." You should fix whichever of those statement is wrong. (I think your title is backwards, and should read "...array does **not** update parent view.")

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct hierarchy is already a view model so just use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In my opinion* using multiple observable objects and a view model class instead of a model struct *is not a good solution*.

I recommend this: `ViewModel` becomes `Model`, a struct which refreshes the view when a member changes, and `ArrayViewModel` becomes `ViewModel`, the **one and only** source of truth.

The child view is connected with a simple standard `@Binding`

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var label: String
    var big: Bool
    
    var state : String {
        big ? "big" : "small"
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Model]

    init(items: [Model] = []) {
        self.items = items
    }
}

struct ContentView1: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel(items: [Model(label: "view ex", big: true)])
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($viewModel.items) { $item in
                Text(item.state)
                Button("outer toggle") {
                    item.big.toggle()
                }
                InnerCard(currentItem: $item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InnerCard: View {
    @Binding var currentItem: Model

    var body: some View {
        Text(currentItem.state)
        Button("inner toggle") {
            currentItem.big.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using structs is not an option for me. I edited my question.

Comment: It's not clear at all **why** it's not an option.

Comment: After a lot of refactoring, I ended up with your solution. I can only support: If someone is facing a similar issue, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The parent view is not being updated because the published property is a collection of classes. Classes are reference values; as long as the same classes are present in the array, the array (and therefore the containing ViewModel) technically did not change. Structs (among other types) are value types, and would propagate the behaviour as you expect.

Since there are  many  ways to reach the wished behaviour which depend on your use case, I would leave the rest to you. :)

Comment: Using structs is not an option for me. I edited my question.